# Loop inside dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm curious if I can make a dict comprehension out of this dict (the frequency of some dice rolls):

```
freq_dict = {}
for i in range(2, max_result+1):
    freq_dict[i] = results.count(i)
```

I can get the right keys when **trying to simplify** this via comprehension but I cannot iterate through the values.

I'm very new to programming and if there is a better way to do this and dict comprehension is not the best one I would like to learn it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
freq_dict = { i: results.count(i) for i in range(2, max_result+1) }
```

Comment: Well... Thanks! I could not understand the syntax very well at the Python Documentation and your answer made it crystal clear for me.